# PHP QRcode como fazer para deixa-lo maior

Tags: php, qrcode

Estou gerando um QRcode através da lib `phpqrcode`. Sei que tem os tamanhos `L`, `H` e outros. Mas, existem formas de deixar a imagem maior usando outras configurações? Pois, mesmo no `H` está pequeno para a minha necessidade.

Eis o meu código

```
require_once "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";

  $code =  $qr;

  QRcode::png($code, "Imagem_QRCODE_H.png", QR_ECLEVEL_H);

  echo '<img src="Imagem_QRCODE_H.png"/>';
```

Comment: Não seria o Cache do seu navegador? Tente isto `echo '<img src="Imagem_QRCODE_H.png?_=' . filemtime('Imagem_QRCODE_H.png') . '"/>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na documentação parece ter algo sobre configurar o tamanho do zoom dos pixels. Imagino que vá resolver seu problema.

```
    include('../lib/full/qrlib.php'); 
    include('config.php'); 

    // how to configure pixel "zoom" factor 

    $tempDir = EXAMPLE_TMP_SERVERPATH; 

    $codeContents = '123456DEMO'; 

    // generating 
    QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir.'007_1.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 1); 
    QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir.'007_2.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 2); 
    QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir.'007_3.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 3); 
    QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir.'007_4.png', QR_ECLEVEL_L, 4); 

    // displaying 
    echo '<img src="'.EXAMPLE_TMP_URLRELPATH.'007_1.png" />'; 
    echo '<img src="'.EXAMPLE_TMP_URLRELPATH.'007_2.png" />'; 
    echo '<img src="'.EXAMPLE_TMP_URLRELPATH.'007_3.png" />'; 
    echo '<img src="'.EXAMPLE_TMP_URLRELPATH.'007_4.png" />';
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> [Documentação](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php?example=007)

***Nota***: Fiz um teste e percebi que a imagem parece não ser sobrescrita quando uma nova é gerada com o mesmo nome, então para fins de testes seria bom apagar a imagem gerada anteriormente ou simplesmente gerar um nome dinâmico com uma hash por exemplo:

```
$nameImg = md5(date('d-m-Y')).'.png';
QRcode::png($codeContents, $tempDir.$nameImg, QR_ECLEVEL_L, 5); 
echo '<img src="'.EXAMPLE_TMP_URLRELPATH.$nameImg'" />';
```

Comment: então.. eu vi essa documentação, mas eu coloco QR_ECLEVEL_H, 4 e não muda nada... fica do mesmo tamanho.

Comment: Vi um configuração aqui agora no documento que me mandou que fez a modificação. Obrigado @DarleiFernandoZilmer